# Is there a way to copy everything that a shortcut redirects to without going inside the shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts, copy-paste

Hi guys basically I am wondering if there is a type of shortcut I can create that when copied copies the entire folder.

Basically I have lots of folders across multiple drives but I want to be able to see all of them in one folder (hence shortcuts) but I would like to be able to just copy the shortcut to copy the files inside the folder it redirects to.

Any ideas/advice?

(windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't state which operating system you are using, so I will assume Windows 7, as that is currently the most common operating system in use.

Windows 7 has Libraries.  Simply add all the applicable folders to a single Library.  Then when you want to copy all the files, just copy the contents of that Library.

You can create as many Libraries as you need.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad to help.